# Suspended camel route reports is not suspended

Tags: apache-camel

I am in the process of developing a message router and part of my design is stopping/suspending and starting/resuming routes based on some file commands dropped in a control route.

I tried to follow the camel recommendations to favor suspend/resume a route as an alternative to stop/start it.

My resume logic depends of the state of some routes say I have two routes ABC and XYZ that cannot be active at the same time. To facilitate this my control route supports two commands `SUSPEND <route id> and RESUME <route id>`. So in short `RESUME XYZ` will do nothing if route ABC is not suspended.

My unit tests (using JMockit) passed OK. However when running the real application I could see the route XYZ never resumes even if I suspended the route ABC before.

I put some log entries and to my surprise after executing the `route.suspend("ABC")` apparently successfully giving the camel log entries the route ABC still reports as not suspended. This is the code:

```
LOGGER.info(r.getId() + " route supports suspension=" + r.supportsSuspension());
context.suspendRoute(r.getId());
LOGGER.info("After suspending route " + r.getId() + " the route suspended state is " + ((ServiceSupport) r).isSuspended());
```

And below are the log entries:

```
[INFO ] my.org.message.router.lifecycle.DeactivateCommand - ABC route supports suspension=true
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Route: ABC suspend complete, was consuming from: Endpoint[abc://queue:SOME_QUEUE]
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 0 seconds
[INFO ] org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Route: ABC is suspended, was consuming from: Endpoint[abc://queue:SOME_QUEUE]
[INFO ] my.org.message.router.lifecycle.DeactivateCommand - After suspending route ABC the route suspended state is false
```

So my questions are:

1. Is this a bug or I am doing it the wrong way
2. If a bug is there a work around or should I go stop/start way
3. If my fault what would be the correct way of achieving what I am after

Thank you in advance for your inputs

Comment: Could be your fault since abc is a custom component, make sure to do your work in doSuspend / doResume methods and not suspend/resume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah that is a bug in Apache Camel to not report the correct state - the route is really suspended. I have logged a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8964

You can get the correct state using `camelContext.getRouteStatus(routeId)` api.

Comment: Hi @Claus what is the event that is triggered when a route is suspended/stopped (idle, no more message is coming ) ?